# Simpler derivation to $\pi$

Tags: calculus, limits, approximation, pi

I'm an amateur in mathematics, being in 9th grade. I have been trying to derive $\pi$. During this I reached a limit to find the value of $\pi$.
$$\lim_{x \to 0}  \frac{180\sin x}{x}$$
Where $x$ is in degree measure.
Isn't this better than the other complex derivations of $\pi$? We just need to set a very small value for x and derive it.

Comment: What do you mean by "derive $\pi$"?

Comment: @avid19 Finding value of it. Atleast that's what I meant.

Comment: I'm afraid that this limit is equal to $180$. What do you mean by saying that $x$ is in degree measure?

Comment: We see complex ways to find the value of pi. But shouldnt this be simpler?

Comment: @N.S.JOHN, perhaps if you typed out your full derivation one can see if it is better.

Comment: $\pi$ is defined as the ratio of a circle's circumference to its diameter. Just to be totally clear, you're asking how we should approximate $\pi$?

Comment: To relate the degree version of $\sin$ to the 'natural' version you need $\pi$, so the above is circular unfortunately.

Comment: What are the complicated definitions you're comparing this one with?

Comment: Your definition depends of $\sin$. And any (valid) definition of $\sin$ is anything but simple.

Comment: @David I have seen some complex formulas which can be seen on Google. I am comparing it with them.

Comment: Do you mean formulas to say, in a simple way, what the number $\pi$ *means* (definitions), or do you mean formulas used to compute $\pi$ with a high degree of accuracy?

Comment: @David the latter one sorry.

Comment: @Rise I imagined a circle to be composed of infinitely small isosceles triangles with the.

Comment: Have you considered that it may be more difficult to get very precise values of $\sin x$ for small values of $x$ in degrees than it is to use those formulas you found to get very precise approximations of $\pi$? I mean, maybe your method takes more calculations to get the same number of digits of $\pi$.

Comment: @David thankyou David that solved my doubts. I imagined all sine values to be known.

Comment: @kamil09875 I have editied the mistake you pointed out. Please withdraw your vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, this limit will yield $\pi$ but take a look at $\sin$. It's "degree" version is defined as

$$\sin_d(x)=\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{180}x\right)$$

Since you can approximate $\sin$ using Taylor series as $$\sin(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$

There is no simple way to calculate $\sin_d$, as in calculations you have to use value of $\pi$.